# Should we prefer vector<unique_ptr<>> or boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, stl

Now with `C++11`, should we prefer `vector<unique_ptr<>>` or `boost::ptr_vector` to store pointer's to objects if we want managed memory?

Comment: I'd suggest ptr_vector because it's a bit simpler conceptually and probably slightly more efficient. Then again, it all depends on use cases

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9469968/1053968) covers some of the differences between the two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `vector<unique_ptr<>>` as it is supported by compiler. no extra effect. otherwise, `boost` need your import into your project.