# std::reverse on boost::ptr_vector slices objects?

Tags: c++, std, swap, boost-ptr-container

Let `Base` and `Derived` be classes with data members:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int i):f(i)     { }
    virtual void print() { cout << "base " << f << endl; }
    int f;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int i):Base(0),g(i) {  }
    void print() { cout << "derived " << g << endl; }
    int g;
};
```

Now create some instances of `Base` and `Derived` on the heap and store them in a `boost::ptr_vector`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::ptr_vector<Base> v;
    v.push_back(new Derived(1));
    v.push_back(new Base(2));
    v.push_back(new Base(3));
    v.push_back(new Derived(4));
```

print all the objects:

```
    for (std::size_t i(0); i != v.size(); ++i)
        v[i].print();
```

then reverse and print again:

```
    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (std::size_t i(0); i != v.size(); ++i)
        v[i].print();
}
```

This program prints:

```
derived 1
base 2
base 3
derived 4
derived 1
base 3
base 2
derived 4
```

`std::reverse()` on `boost::ptr_vector` calls `std::iter_swap()` which in turn calls `std::swap` which swaps items by creating a temporary copy.

However, the temporary copy does slice the Derived objects. As you can see, the `int g` of the `Derived` objects 1 and 4 are *not* swapped, so the objects are broken after the swap.

This behavior puzzles me. Isn't `boost::ptr_vector` a container to avoid exactly this kind of problem?

What I'd need here is a *virtual copy constructor*, which doesn't exist in C++.

How can I work around this? Do I need to implement a virtual swap function for `Base`, so that virtual dispatching calls another swap member function of `Derived`?

EDIT: Why copy objects in the first place? As the vector only stores pointers, reversing it should be a swap of the pointers, not the objects pointed to!
Is there a function that does that?

Comment: According to the FAQ for Ptr Containers for which mutating algorithms are okay, "Any mutating algorithm that moves elements around by swapping them."

Comment: yes, but the elements of a ptr_vector are pointers, not objects. So it should be swapping the pointers, instead of swapping and slicing objects.

Comment: It gets better: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#algorithms says 'algorithms are available as member functions'. Indeed, there's a boost::ptr_vector::reverse(). But when I call this, I get a compile error: 'No member named 'reverse' in 'std::vector<void *, std::allocator<void *> >'

Comment: The "virtual copy constructor" is handled in ptr_container with the "clonable" concept -- nonmember `new_clone` and `delete_clone` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html#the-clonable-concept

Comment: Consider `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` instead.

Comment: I second Billy ONeal's suggestion.  Here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9472379/576911) is a rather long winded rationale for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible work around is to use

```
std::reverse(v.base().begin(), v.base().end());
```

instead. It reverses the pointers instead of the self-indirecting iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Boost's `ptr_vector` class contains member functions whose job is manipulate the underlying pointers. But the public interface largely hides the fact that the vector internally stores pointers. The idea is to produce something that behaves as if it contained the objects directly but internally stores pointers to avoid slicing when you put an object into the container. But if you copy an object out of the container into an object of the base type, then it will slice. So you must not call such functions on `ptr_vector`s.

This means, unfortunately, that before you apply any algorithm to a `ptr_vector`, you need to understand exactly what it does.